# Have item in a drop down list be selected from another drop down list and variables

Tags: c#, asp.net, database, gridview, drop-down-menu

I have a page with a drop down list and Once I select an item it goes to another page with a Gridview. In the Gridview it displays the data from a database. There are two drop down lists in each the Gridview row. One of the drop down lists is the same drop down list on the previous page. I need this drop down list to have the item that was selected from the previous page be the item selected in the drop down list. The second drop down list needs to have a selected value that comes from the database.

I have the database part working, but I do not know how to set the drop down lists.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: that sounds nice however this is not a `CodeFactory Site` and you need to show us what you have tried on your own.. good luck and come back when you have tried something / stuck in regards to code..

Comment: Pease provide your gridview mark up. Is the second page the result of a postback or a redirect?

Answer (score 0):

***ddlStatus*** is the dropdownlist. 
***findSIndex*** is the selected item from the dropdownlist on the previous page.
***gvReviewStatus*** is the Gridview on the page

```
for (int count = 0; count < gvReviewStatus.Rows.Count; count++)
            {
                ((DropDownList)gvReviewStatus.Rows[count].FindControl("ddlStatus")).SelectedIndex = findSIndex;



            }
```